# Redux load user, but it get html code (MERN App when deploy Heroku)

Tags: reactjs, redux, mern

I created a MERN app which runs perfectly on localhost. When I deploy the same to heroku, it had problem when loadUser, it cannot get user object, instead get html code (please see the picture below)

[cannot get user, it get html code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vW2Qi.png)

Link app: https://tuong-instagram.herokuapp.com/

Link repo: https://github.com/huynhdieutuong/MERN_Instagram-Clone

Please help me. Thanks!

> Build Log

```
-----> Node.js app detected

-----> Creating runtime environment

       NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
       NODE_ENV=production
       NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
       NODE_VERBOSE=false

-----> Installing binaries
       engines.node (package.json):  unspecified
       engines.npm (package.json):   unspecified (use default)

       Resolving node version 12.x...
       Downloading and installing node 12.16.3...
       Using default npm version: 6.14.4

-----> Restoring cache
       - node_modules

-----> Installing dependencies
       Installing node modules (package.json + package-lock)
       audited 275 packages in 2.24s

       12 packages are looking for funding
         run `npm fund` for details

       found 0 vulnerabilities


-----> Build
       Running heroku-postbuild

       > instagram_clone@1.0.0 heroku-postbuild /tmp/build_50c620997e1e9cf5e52b891e82486dda
       > NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false npm install --prefix client && npm run build --prefix client


       > core-js@2.6.11 postinstall /tmp/build_50c620997e1e9cf5e52b891e82486dda/client/node_modules/babel-runtime/node_modules/core-js
       > node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"


       > core-js@3.6.5 postinstall /tmp/build_50c620997e1e9cf5e52b891e82486dda/client/node_modules/core-js
       > node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"


       > core-js-pure@3.6.5 postinstall /tmp/build_50c620997e1e9cf5e52b891e82486dda/client/node_modules/core-js-pure
       > node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"

       added 1734 packages from 828 contributors and audited 1739 packages in 46.142s

       60 packages are looking for funding
         run `npm fund` for details

       found 1 low severity vulnerability
         run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details

       > client@0.1.0 build /tmp/build_50c620997e1e9cf5e52b891e82486dda/client
       > react-scripts build

       Creating an optimized production build...
       Compiled successfully.

       File sizes after gzip:

         151.36 KB  build/static/js/2.bcf86cda.chunk.js
         63.06 KB   build/static/css/2.4c6ee7a4.chunk.css
         13.51 KB   build/static/js/main.ffa55597.chunk.js
         4.28 KB    build/static/css/main.30d556c6.chunk.css
         774 B      build/static/js/runtime-main.8c40394c.js

       The project was built assuming it is hosted at /.
       You can control this with the homepage field in your package.json.

       The build folder is ready to be deployed.
       You may serve it with a static server:

         npm install -g serve
         serve -s build

       Find out more about deployment here:

         bit.ly/CRA-deploy


-----> Caching build
       - node_modules

-----> Pruning devDependencies
       removed 172 packages and audited 102 packages in 3.444s

       1 package is looking for funding
         run `npm fund` for details

       found 0 vulnerabilities


-----> Build succeeded!
-----> Discovering process types
       Procfile declares types     -> (none)
       Default types for buildpack -> web
-----> Compressing...
       Done: 81.2M
-----> Launching...
       Released v4
       https://tuong-instagram.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku
```

Comment: link is not working and moreover pls provide error logs or something that can help understand the issue

Comment: @Dlucidone I just checked the link, it still works.  and it does not show the error in the log.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use proxy when you make requests from Heroku app to Instagram, it seems that Instagram somehow blocks requests from Heroku domain

Comment: Okay. Let me try it. Thank you.